# cudaGetDeviceCount return 1 instead of 2

Tags: windows, cuda, tesla

I've a gpu cluster composed of 2 Tesla M2050 and when I'm executing my code, cudaGetDeviceCount returns only 1. If I try to set the device 1 with cudaSetDevice it give me this error: invalid device ordinals. In the device manager of windows both the devices are listed. If needed this is my source code

```
cutilSafeCall(cudaGetDeviceCount(&num_devices));

for (device = 0; device < num_devices; device++) {
      cudaDeviceProp properties;
      cudaGetDeviceProperties(&properties, device);
      printf("Device ID:\t%d\n", device);
      printf("Device Name:\t%s\n", properties.name );
      printf("Global memory:\t%d\n", properties.totalGlobalMem );
      printf("Constant memory:\t%d\n", properties.totalConstMem );
      printf("Warp size:\t%d\n", properties.warpSize );
}
devs=0;
ParseArguments(argc, argv);
cutilSafeCall(cudaSetDevice(devs));
```

any help would be appreciated

edit: output of deviceQuery.exe

```
deviceQuery.exe Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

There is 1 device supporting CUDA

Device 0: "Tesla M2050"   
CUDA Driver Version: 5.50
CUDA Runtime Version:                          4.20   
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0  
...
...

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 5.50, CUDA Runtime Vers ion = 4.20, NumDevs = 1, Device = Tesla M2050


PASSED

Press <Enter> to Quit...
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Try running the deviceQuery example from samples and see if it returns properly.

Comment: It always shows me only one device.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two CUDA GPUs in a single node and deviceQuery only reports one, then consider the following possibilities:

- Check both GPUs are functioning correctly by running nvidia-smi, if only one is shown then check it is socketed correctly.
- Check the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is not set.

Comment: actually nvidia-smi reported an error, but I don't really know what is it...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9wmkdrlukmam4i/nvsmi.png

Comment: From what I've seen in past threads, a reboot should be enough... 
I still have to understand how a cuda application can generate that error